# Does anyone used Django-postman for implementing private chat?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am newbie to programming as well as in Django framework, recently I am creating a website that user can chat **1 to 1 "private chat"** I found lot of tutorials, like creating Django chat with django-channels every on of them are creating with chatroom, I like to implement 1 to 1 chat. is there any tutorial in Django-postman or does anyone created chat with django-postman? if you anyone came across any alternative that would be helpful.

Any advice?

Comment: https://django-postman.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: However, if you want to build a real-time chat application, using Django Channels would be a better option as it provides the necessary functionality to build real-time applications using WebSockets. There are many tutorials available for building real-time chat applications using Django Channels, which you can find online.

Comment: I think most them are creating the chatroom and using that chatroom they can chat. I like to implement private chat. do you came across any tutorials in that?

Comment: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/consumers.html#django-chat-tutorial This tutorial provided by Django Channels itself demonstrates how to build a simple chat application that includes private chat functionality.